# How to render only the inside of a sphere in Camera in unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a sphere with two materials which is having two shaders. Outside of the sphere is masked using a Depthmask shader and inside of the sphere is in desired colour(red) with InsideOut shader. The camera passes from one point to another and back to origin through the sphere center to see a red circle coming an going.Using an orthogonal camera.

The issue is if the sphere is in front of the camera it is rendered as a black circle even thought I am using Depthmask shaders. I want to see what is behind the sphere. Only when I enter the sphere the inside of the sphere should be visible.

[image: Sphere rendered as black.Background in green colour]
[image: Sphere with DepthMask shader and inside red colour]

Comment: might want to look into [stencil buffer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html) see also https://www.ronja-tutorials.com/post/022-stencil-buffers/